# Documentation regarding VMware Workstation 12 Player configuration files?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

**Configuration files:**

- *%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\VMware\preferences.ini*
- *%ProgramData%\VMware\VMware Workstation\config.ini*
- *%ProgramData%\VMware\VMware Workstation\settings.ini*

Such are the relevant configuration files installed alongside my copy of VMware Workstation 12 Player. I presume they are also relevant for VMware Workstation 12 Pro.

I've crawled the VMware site for ages, and I have yet to discover any documentation detailing the options available in these files. This is just a last ditch effort - I'm wondering if anyone has the documentation or a link... I'm aware that some people have compiled "de facto" lists on their own blogs but they appear to be incomplete and outdated. I'm really just looking for official documents.

Does any documentation exist? Did it ever exist? Do you have it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no official documentation.

The configuration files are basically like the Windows registry: they allow users to hand-edit them as a last resort, but hand-editing them will never be officially supported, and therefore there very likely will never be comprehensive, official documentation for all of them.

Comment: So you're saying there's no documentation for the Windows registry either? Well... I guess that's one reason people like open-source so much.

Comment: I'm saying that while individual entries might be documented (for either VMware configuration files or for the Windows registry), you're never going to get complete documentation for everything that's in it.  Many of the things in them are *intentionally* not documented so that people don't touch them and shoot themselves in the foot or so that they don't need to be supported.  This has nothing to do with closed-source vs open-source; Mozilla Firefox is OSS but does not provide end-user documentation for everything in about:config either.

Comment: Looking back on it, I wasn't clear. I was alluding to the fact that you can read the source code directly if there's no relevant documentation. But to be honest, I probably wouldn't bother to do that.

Comment: Sure, of course.  I meant that you originally asked for official, *de jure* documentation, but even if you can look at the source code, you'd still be getting only *de facto* documentation (because the way that code actually works and the way that it's expected to work might be different).  The unofficial lists compiled on the web are your best bet.  If there are specific options you want to know about, you could ask on VMware's community forums, and someone might explain them.